# Is it appropriate to use pattern Strategy in this task?

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have a task to build a program that calculates taxes from the person. For example, some taxes are calculated the same, so can I relate it to Strategy pattern?

I think I can create a lot of classes of taxes, but I don't think it's effective. Maybe, you can advise another pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [wiki says about strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

> the strategy pattern (also known as the policy pattern) is a
> behavioral software design pattern that enables selecting an algorithm
> at runtime. Instead of implementing a single algorithm directly, code
> receives run-time instructions as to **which in a family of algorithms
> to use**

Your `Taxes` classes look like family of interchangealble algorithms. So it can be concluded that it is appropriate to use Strategy pattern here.